# admin icon not clickable after update magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3.5

admin icon not clickable after update Magento 2.3.5 when mode change to production mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

and when change to  `bin/magento deploy:mode:set default` then icon is clickable

Comment: Icon showing properly???

Comment: @MohitPatel yes please see image https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhRDpT0hepo5jkRDXWKwpj3RtBOx?e=n4jUx4

Comment: You run deploy command??? If no try deploy command

Comment: @MohitPatel yes

Comment: i am not sure but you go to app/etc/di.xml file open and search this  Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy and last add Copy `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy` after run all command

Comment: After set default mode. You have to run all the command setup:upgrade and static:content:deploy and setup:di:compile

Comment: @KarangarMeghnathi  run all commad but when mode change to production mode then still not work